# Can I access a folder right after it's created

Tags: file, rust, system

This maybe because I'm used to backend and async in js but if I type this in rust..

```
fs::create_dir("dir1")
```

Then use

```
fs::File::create("dir1/file1.txt")
```

To create a file in the new folder right after,
is it bound to go wrong, should the program sleep for a second to make sure the directory has already been created on the environment?

Comment: Sleeping to ensure correct timing is a terrible, terrible hack. Anyway, `create_dir()` is synchronous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer this, No it is not bound to go wrong.
And also to add in general, sleeping to ensure that something is being done is not that of a good idea.

In the case you provided, [`fs::create_dir`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/fn.create_dir.html) is sync and it returns a Result type. So before you create file inside `dir1` make sure you check the result is ok. And also check the result for creating file is ok.

```rust
fn create_file(){
    if fs::create_dir("dir1").is_ok() {
        if fs::File::create("dir1/file1.txt").is_ok() {
           println!("File created inside dir1"); 
       }
    }
}
```

Also, while inside rust you can take the gurantee that once directory is created it stays there but this won't always be case. For example, a system might have a background job that keeps deleting the directory inside some place. Hopefully, you don't always have to worry about all these extreme cases but just so you know ;)